# Definição do "margin-top" em porcentagem de uma "div" funciona de forma estranha

Tags: html, css

Possuo uma página `.xhtml` e o primeiro elemento a ser colocado é uma `div`(*content*) e eu defino para ela uma margem superior(`margin-top`) de 30%.

Supostamente, pelo que entendo, esta porcentagem deveria ser tirada a altura da minha tela, no meu caso tenho uma tela de 1600 × 795 e os 30% seriam tirados dos 795px.

Vejam o que acontece:

```css
#content
{
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 50%;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

No exemplo eu coloque 50% de `margin-top` para poder passar a percepção do que ocorre. Ele deveria estar a 50% do topo mais parece ter descido muito mais.

Comment: O Fiddle não está passando a ideia a 100% mas acredito que já ajuda.

Answer (score 3):

Realmente se você for simplesmente pela lógica daria a entender que o `margin-top` e `margin-bottom` quando especificados em `%` seriam um valor referente a altura do elemento pai, porém não é assim que funciona.

Quando a margem é especificada em '%' ela sempre vai ser referente a largura (`width`) do elemento pai, você pode conferir isso facilmente redimensionando a janela, você vai ver que o elemento vai mudar de posição apenas quando você alterar a largura da janela.

Comment: É isso mesmo que ocorre, como se pode ler na especificação: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Answer (score 0):

Mexi um pouco no seu CSS e ta ai:

```css
#content
{
width: 300px;
height: 200px;
position: absolute;
top: 0; 
bottom: 0;
left: 0; 
right: 0;
margin: auto;
background: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
</div>
```

Creio que assim já resolva seu problema

Comment: obrigado, mas a minhq questão não é fazer a coisa funcionar é perceber como ela funciona. A tua solução centraliza totalmente o elemento (se percebi bem), mas no meu exemplo eu queria perceber porquê o `margin-top` funcionou do jeito que funcionou.

Comment: então realmente sua pergunta não foi muito clara ... ou devo ter algum problema mental rs

Answer (score 0):

adiciona no css da div `#content`

```
display: table-caption;
```

Comment: A sua resposta ficaria mais completa se você adicionasse uma pequena explicação em como isso resolve o problema.

Answer (score 0):

Como já foi dito, margin e padding com porcentagem, utilizam da largura do elemento. O margin se baseia no elemento pai. E o padding se baseia no próprio elemento.

Se sua intenção era que o elemento, ou seja, seu ***#content*** fique centralizado, você deve fazer como no exemplo a seguir.

```
 #content {
     position: absolute;
     display: block;
     width: 200px;
     height: 200px;
     top: calc(50% - 100px);
     left: calc(50% - 100px);
 }
```

no exemplo eu digo que meu *#content* terá uma distância de 50% do topo do próximo elemento pai que tenha *position: relative*, menos a metade da altura do meu elemento, pois quando usamos o atributo *top*, ele se referencia pelo topo do elemento e não pelo centro. Do mesmo jeito para o *left*, só que a distância é de 50% menos a metade da largura do elemento.